# Transitive inclusion of @Configuration classes from a .xml-based spring config

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

Suppose we start with an xml-based config, say `main.xml`, that imports a java config `FullConfig.java` via:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="test.FullConfig"/>
```

This java config has the form:

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {IncludeConfig.class})
public class FullConfig {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "tmpBean")
    private DataClazz autowired;

    @Bean
    public DataClazz someOtherBean() {
        System.out.println("Using autowired tmpBean:" + autowired);
        return new DataClazz();
    }
}
```

so it imports a further java config, which contains a definition of the `tmpBean` of `DataClazz` type,

```
@Configuration
public class IncludeConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataClazz tmpBean() {
        return new DataClazz();
    }
}
```

Now two questions:

1. Is this "transitive inclusion" guaranteed to work in spring (i.e. is `someOtherBean()` guaranteed not to thrown a NPE)?
2. IntelliJ up to version 2017.2 does mark `@Qualifier(value = "tmpBean")` red with a message "Cannot find bean with qualifier 'tmpBean'". Should that be considered a bug?

Note: I have checked that an application using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("main.xml")` does work correctly, i.e. no NPE is thrown (and all relevant beans are visible).

Answer (score 1):

You need to return DataClazz:

```
@Bean
public DataClazz someOtherBean() {
    System.out.println("Using autowired tmpBean:" + autowired);
    return autowired;
}
```

1. Probably yes but try to test it.
2. IDEA-82844 (Bug)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the type in `someOtherBean()`; corrected. On (1) I did try and it seems to work; however we have similar problems in much more complicated environment, so I'd like to know if this is guaranteed to work by spring (say, spring 4.0.6+). On (2): contrary to IDEA-82844 IntelliJ really thinks there is no such bean; navigation (ctrl+mouse click does not work).